# Securing an existing API behind AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, client-certificates

Suppose I have a RESTful API that sits on a Windows EC2 cluster, behind an ELB. The existing API is a .NET application and hosted in IIS.

I want to try and put AWS API Gateway in front of the existing API, so that security, scalability, etc. is handled by AWS. Essentially set up AWS Gateway as a HTTP proxy to the existing API.

From the AWS documentation it states that the existing API must be made public. But it should be secured by verifying the calls are originating from Amazon API Gateway by checking the client side certificate.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

However the SSL connections for the existing API are terminated at the ELB. Hence when we check the client certificate, on the request, in code - it doesn't exist.

What would need to be done to get the client certificate at the EC2/IIS/code level?

Or is there an alternative way to secure the existing API and ensure AWS API Gateway can still communicate with it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to configure your set up your ELB to do TCP based load balancing and terminate SSL connection on your IIS/EC2 hosts. This will require distributing the SSL certificate to the hosts and configuring them to bind the certificate to the appropriate port.

Answer (score 2):

Usually people prefer to offload SSL at their API gateway to save administrative overhead since ELB termination effectively moves the management to a single point in the infrastructure, rather than requiring management of the SSL certs on multiple servers.

It also helps if you are having a EC2 cluster managed by some orchestrator [ECS, kubernetes, Docker Swarm].  As you already mentioned that API gateway to load  balancer is secured by SSL certificates, you can add access policy at load balancer to provide required permission to interact with your EC2 cluster, while your EC2 exist in private VPC, you may don't need to add certificates to your EC2 machines as all communication is already secured.

Hope it make sense.